# Problema ao conectar vários bancos de dados CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho um aplicação em que ela se conecta a vários banco de dados, inicialmente uso as configurações do banco do arquivo *database.php*.

Só que quando vou conectar a outro banco, ele ainda carrega as configurações do arquivo *database.php*, sendo que faço da seguinte forma para fazer a segunda conexão:

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$this->load->database($config);
```

Comment: Supondo que a sua *array* de configurações seja [assim],(http://pastebin.com/fmCra9vy) basta carregar as informações deste outro DB deste modo: `$DB2 = $this->load->database('outrodb', TRUE);` Isso provavelmente resolveria.

Comment: Também vi essa possibilidade, mas tem um problema, o hostname desta outra conexão esta armazenado em uma sessão, sendo assim, não consigo recupera o valor desta sessão no arquivo database.php

Answer (score 5):

Você deve alterar as configurações de acesso a seu banco de dados principal em seu arquivo application/configdatabase.php para:

```
$config['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['default']['username'] = "myusername";
$config['default']['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['default']['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$config['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Em seguida, algumas linhas acima, no mesmo arquivo, defina o grupo do banco de dados principal:

```
$active_group = 'default';
```

Ainda no mesmo arquivo, para cada outro banco de dados que você precise se conectar, crie um novo grupo de configurações, alterando a identificação do grupo e as configurações de conexão:

```
$config['secundario']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['secundario']['username'] = "myusername";
$config['secundario']['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['secundario']['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['secundario']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['secundario']['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['secundario']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['secundario']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['secundario']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['secundario']['cachedir'] = "";
$config['secundario']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['secundario']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Em seus métodos quando chamar $this->db você estará atuando no banco de dados principal. Sempre que quiser atuar sobre outro banco de dados, basta carregá-lo dinamicamente, da seguinte maneira:

```
$bd_secundario = $this->load->database('secundario', TRUE);
```

Após o carregamento, você pode operar sobre ele da mesma maneira que em `$this->db`, como por exemplo,

```
$bd_secundario->query('SELECT * FROM world').
```